# Extending the tangent bundle of a submanifold to a subbundle of the manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Given an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$, and an $n$-dimensional submanifold $N$, with $n<m$, the tangent bundle of $N$ is a smooth $n$-dimensional subbundle of $TM|_N$.

When can $TN$ be extended to an $n$-dimensional subbundle of $TM$?

There are obvious examples where it's easy to extend $TN$ to a subbundle of $TM$, but for a spiral in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or the equator in a sphere it is not possible.

Edit - It's interesting to note that a sphere doesn't admit any $1$-dimensional subbundle. On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}^2$ obviously admits a $1$-dimensional subbundle, but still the tangent bundle of the spiral can't be extended to a full subbundle. Similar "spiral"-like submanifolds of any dimension $1 \le n < m$ can be found for every $m$-dimensional manifold.

Cross posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430737/extending-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-submanifold-to-a-subbundle-of-the-manifold)

Comment: You want to extend $TN$ to a $m$-dimensional subbundle of $TM$? Is already a $n$-dimensional subbundle

Comment: No, I want to extend it to an $n$-dimensional subbundle of $TM$. It is not a subbundle of $TM$ yet - it is only defined on $N$, not on all of $M$.

Comment: get it, my bad haha